# How to set android WiFi hotspot password on Android 4.1.2

Tags: wifi-tethering

On most operating systems, you can set up name, password and encryption type for your WiFi hospot. For some reason, Android only has this switch to enable/disable it:

[image: image description]

When I enable it WiFi `Android AP` is created. Of course, I can't connect because I don't know the password. I would also like to change the name.

I also looked in Security and WiFi settings sections but nothing there either. What's wrong with Android?

Comment: On my Xperia S (also running 4.1.2) it's listed above Bluetooth tethering  on that same menu.  I've seen on other devices it only appears after you've turned Portable Wi-Fi hotspot on.

Comment: Is the device rooted? If yes, can you confirm whether the file `/data/misc/wifi/softap.conf` exist? If yes, what does it contain? (Note: the file should be containing SSID and password of hotspot). The SSID would also be available from `/data/misc/wifi/hostapd.conf` or wherever your device stores `hostapd.conf`. Some devices don't even use `hostapd.conf` to manage hotspot.

Comment: @Firelord No, the device is not rooted. I also didn't try to alter configuration program in any way, so settings should be on their places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access the hotspot settings you have to keep (tap-hold) your finger on the same field *Portable Wi-Fi hotspot* for a few seconds, then release the finger. 
Unless there's a menu icon (three dots) on the top right corner, in which case you can access the settings by tapping on the menu icon and choosing *Configure*.

Generally speaking, in most apps you can tap-hold on a field to pop up a list of options. This is not very intuitive at a first glance, but after you've used Android for a while it becomes natural.

Comment: I tried that already. I will try once more to make sure but I'm little bit sceptical.

Comment: Try to do that both with the hotspot turned on and turned off, just in case.

Comment: The problem is one has actually to **release** the finger without moving it much. Normally, the toutch and hold gesture works so that you don't have to release the button.

Comment: yes, releasing the finger does solve it. Maybe @dr01 can include this in his/her answer? / This is the most horrible thing I have witnessed all day

Comment: @Blauhirn Done.